# Interaction between 2 programs

Tags: vb.net

From my `*.vb` file I have to run a `*.tcl` file for which this same program runs a `*.bat` .If I run my program from `*.vb` my file `*.bat` runs but I don’t have the result as it should. If I don’t use my `*.vb` file everything works

```
file.vb :
    ------ > myfile.tcl
        -----> exec file.bat
```

From vb below my function :

```
        Try

            Dim form As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            form.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput  = False
            form.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError   = False
            form.StartInfo.UseShellExecute         = False
            form.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow          = True
            form.StartInfo.Arguments               = myfile.tcl
            form.StartInfo.FileName                = wish.exe
            form.Start()

        Catch ex As Exception

            Console.Writeline(ex.ToString())
            Return False

        End Try

        Return True
```

My question is: do I use my function well ? If no , what is the best solution ? if so where do you think it can come from?

Comment: What *should* the result be? What result does it actually give?

Comment: @Andrew Morton Since my bat file I run a program in java which generates an html file following a template this html file is incomplete if I run it from my .vb

Comment: Could you generate the HTML file in your program instead?

Comment: what I have not tried and what would be possible is to launch my *.bat  from vb without going through my tcl file but is this the right use of System.Diagnostics.Process()?

Comment: Does the incomplete part give you any hints as to what is not working?

Comment: the only thing I see is that the template file is not the right one, because my template file is different

Comment: Have you tried setting the [ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory)?

Comment: I have tried but same result, I have tried with my *.bat too and same result , I don’t understand...

Comment: Make sure you use the full path for the template file, not just its filename.

Comment: thanks @Andrew Morton for the help as well as for your patience , I finally found but I still don’t understand , in my file `*.bat` I have variables and my template was related to this variable , I forced the full path and now it works but why it’s different since vb.net I don’t know how to answer